# How to add a target into the end of src quotes

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, src, targeting

so I would like to know how you would add a target in this example "google-iframe" into the source link of the iframe.

Here is the current code I have:

```
<!-- CSS -->
<style>
        body {
    color: purple;
    background-color: #663300 }
    </style>

<form target="google-iframe">
       <input id="search" type="text"/>
      <input type="image" onclick="google-iframe" src="Searchbutton.png" alt="Search Button" height="20" width="20">
      <iframe id="google-iframe" src="http://www.google.com/custom?q=" width="250" height="600" onmouseover="width=400" onmouseout="width=250" onclick="window.location='http://www.google.com/custom?q=Test&btnG=Search'"></iframe>
</form>
```

I would like to have it be like this:

```
 <iframe id="google-iframe" src="http://www.google.com/custom?q=" + "google-iframe" width="250" height="600" onmouseover="width=400" onmouseout="width=250" onclick="window.location='http://www.google.com/custom?q=Test&btnG=Search'"></iframe>
```

the change was that were it says

```
src=http://www.google.com/custome?q=
```

what ever is defined as "google-iframe" would be inserted at the end of the src for like this for example

```
src=http://www.google.com/custome?q=WhatEverIsEntedInTheGoogle-Iframe
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You need to use the `name` attribute for targeting to an `iframe` and not the `id`
2. You need to set the action of the `form` to be the url that will be loaded in the `iframe`
3. You need to name (*using the attribute `name` again*) the input element with the keywords as `q` as that is what google expects.

So something like this

```
<form action="http://www.google.com/custom" target="google-iframe" method="get">
    <input name="q" type="text" />
    <input type="image" onclick="google-iframe" src="Searchbutton.png" alt="Search Button" height="20" width="20"/>
</form>

<iframe name="google-iframe" src="http://www.google.com/custom" width="250" height="600" onmouseover="width=400" onmouseout="width=250" onclick="window.location='http://www.google.com/custom?q=Test&btnG=Search'"></iframe>
```

Demo at http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/4bAjT/1/

---

**Update after comments**
*to account for multiple `iframes` with different rules for the submitting url*

**Html**

```
<form onsubmit="return virtualSubmit(this)";>
    <input name="searchtext" type="text" />
    <input type="image" src="Searchbutton.png" alt="Search Button" height="20" width="20"/>
</form>

<iframe src="http://www.google.com/custom"
        data-url="http://www.google.com/custom?q="
        width="250"
        height="600"></iframe>

<iframe src="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki"
        data-url="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/"
        width="250"
        height="600"></iframe>
```

and **javascript**

```
function virtualSubmit(form){
    var text = form.searchtext.value;
    var targets = document.getElementsByTagName('iframe'),
        items = targets.length;

    for(var i = 0; i<items; i++){
        var target = targets[i],
            url = target.getAttribute('data-url');
        target.src = url + text;
    }

    return false;
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much! Exactly what I was looking for and saved me tons of time :)

Comment: Although how would I search multiple iframes at once? like i would want to seach the same thing but lets say on wiki and diction iframes but all off of the same search bar.

Comment: hm @Gaby, is there anyway you could show a demo or somethings?

Comment: Have a look at http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/4bAjT/2/ In effect you need to specify the parameter name and url for each frame and then loop over them..

Comment: (*i have used random values for the second iframe as i do not know what is expected to search for wiki and dictionary*)

Comment: Oh, I see... thank you so much man, you've been a huge help with a project i'm working on!

Comment: one last thing so wiki and deffination have it as / than the name of what your searching but google has it as ?q= how would i do 2 different ones?

Comment: then just use the whole url up to the point where the parameter is added and skip the dynamic parameter we used in the previous try.. [**see demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/4bAjT/3/)

Comment: Oh Awesome it works with all the websites but just one question for future versions is it possible for me to assign witch iframes show up using a custom algorithm that takes what you said in the text and finds the best result?

Comment: @Ibounes i do not believe you can look inside the contents of the iframes because they are from differen domains.. If you describe in more detail what you want to do i could suggest something..